# Were combos introduced with the Origin Island DLC?

Tags: fantasy-life

I recently picked up playing Fantasy Life again, after a couple of months. I did not had the DLC yet, but when I reached Legend in a couple of lives and hungry for more, I decided to buy it.

During one of my first battles with the DLC installed, I noticed that there were combos with my magician, which I could not remember to see before. For example, button smashing <kbd>A</kbd> as a fire mage yielded stream of flames after a couple of hits, instead of the 'normal' fireballs. Was this introduced with the DLC, or did I miss it completely during the normal game?

I could not find anything about it on Wikia (searching for [combos](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=combo&fulltext=Search) or the [DLC](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/wiki/Origin_Island)).

Comment: Looking into things a bit further; if you look at your licenses and hit X a couple times to view page(s) 3+ of the wizard license, it will show you all the commands. I started the Wizard life to test things, and at fledgling rank the only fire magic I have access to is **Fairy Fire** (basic attack with fire selected) and **Fireball** (charged fire attack). Currently locked fire based commands are: **Firesplosion**, **Fire Storm**, and **Wall of Fire**. If you have more than those, then the ranks introduced by the DLC did enable new magic combo attacks.

Comment: I've got fairy fire, heavy flame (after third strike of fairy fire, is the accompanying text), flame shot (locked) and the rest you mentioned. So indeed, the heavy flame is added. You can add that as an answer. Thanks for your investigation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the DLC does add new combos for the wizard life. You can view the commands available for any life path by selecting the license, and pressing <kbd>X</kbd> a number of times to view the various pages of commands/skills available to that particular life.

In the base game, the skills available to a wizard are:

- **Fairy Fire**, **Snowball**, **Windcutter**, **Sapling Heal** (*All ranks*)

  - Press <kbd>A</kbd> to use the basic attack (or heal) of the selected element.
- **Fireball**, **Icy Breath**, **Air Sickle**, **Flower Heal** (*Fledgling+*)

  - Hold then release <kbd>A</kbd> for a charged attack (or heal) of the selected element.
- **Firesplosion**, **Snapfreese**, **Razor Wind**, **Healing Forest**  (*Expert+*)

  - Hold <kbd>A</kbd> for longer and release for a stronger charged attack (or heal) of the selected element.
- **Fire Storm**, **Ice Storm**, **Thunder Storm**, **Healing Meadow** (*Apprentice+*)

  - Hold then release <kbd>X</kbd> for a special attack (or heal) of the selected element.
- **Wall of Fire**, **Blizzard**, **Cosmic Thunder**, **Nature's Bounty** (*Expert+*)

  - Hold <kbd>X</kbd> for longer and release for a stronger special attack (or heal) of the selected element.
- **Falling Star** (*Adept to Expert*)

  - Press <kbd>X</kbd> when special gauge is full.
- **Shooting Star** (*Master (to God-in-Training)*)

  - Press <kbd>X</kbd> when special gauge is full.

With the additional ranks from the DLC, there are added commands for each element:

- **Heavy Flame**, **Iceball**, **Galeforce**, **Sappling Aid** (*God-in-Training+*)

  - Combo attacks initiated by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> after using the basic attack three times in a row.
- **Flame Shot**, **Iceball Slam**, **Bolt Strike**, **Sappling Cure** (*God-in-Training+*)

  - Stronger combo attacks initiated by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> after using the above Combo Skill.
- **Meteodrive** (*God*)

  - Press <kbd>X</kbd> when special gauge is full.
- **Ancient Wisdom** (*God*)

  - Press <kbd>X</kbd> when special gauge is filled twice.

I found all the command information for the Wizard life, as well as the commands for all the other lives [here](http://www.gamerguides.com/fantasy-life/life-walkthrough/magician/information-and-controls/recruitable-allies/rank) (may require a facebook login).